# Update Product Name, Description, Short Description in Magento

Tags: sql, magento

The solution for this was almost provided in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249171
It does indeed replace the product name properly.

But I needed to take it a step further and check the productname, description and short description to replace 'example' with 'test' in all three areas. I wasn't sure if it was possible to modify the current script provided to include these other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

this do the trick :

```
$newName = str_replace('example','test',$product->getName());
$product->setName($newName);
```

Find it and add the other attributes :

```
$newDescription = str_replace('example','test',$product->getDescription());
$product->setDescription($newDescription);
$newShortDescription = str_replace('example','test',$product->getShortDescription());
$product->setShortDescription($newShortDescription);
```

Then save each attribute like this :

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'description');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'short_description');
```

Or just save the product (time and resource consuming)

```
$product->save();
```

To select only product having example in name OR description OR short_desc use this

```
 -addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'name','like'=>'%example%'), array('attribute'=>'description','like'=>'%example%'),array('attribute'=>'short_description','like'=>'%example%')))
```

Instead of

```
->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like','%example%'))
```

Comment: Do I need to modify the line above it to search for the description with that context? $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like'=>'%example%'));

Comment: I tried that edit but then it gives this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH on line 33

Comment: you have a trailing semi-colon on line 32 ?